# DS.store.find() using two params result in an error

Tags: ember.js

i have a strange behavior:

If I call

```
this.store.find('uilabel', { locale: "en" });
```

it returns the result of /uielements?locale=en as I expect.

but if I add another parameter like

```
this.store.find('uilabel', { locale: "en", device: "mobile" });
```

I get this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: Error: No model was found for 'device'
```

Ember correctly starts a GET-request to /uielements?locale=en&device=mobile which is responded

Does anyone know why this happens?

EDIT: 
Here is the uilabel-model. So far, it is as primitive as it could be :)

```
Application.Uilabel = DS.Model.extend({
    locale:     DS.attr('string'),
    key:        DS.attr('string'),
    value:      DS.attr('string'),
    device:     DS.attr('string'),
});
```

EDIT2:
Sry, i could provide it by myself... here the JSON-response:

```
uilabels?locale=en&device=web

{
    "locale": "en",
    "device": "web",
    "key": "server_url_dialog_default_button",
    "value": "en_test"
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you also add your uilabel model to the question?

Comment: and maybe also the json response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue may be that the JSON response is not in the format that Ember Data is expecting.  See http://emberjs.com/guides/models/connecting-to-an-http-server/.  According to the spec, your JSON response needs to be in this format:

```
{
    uilabels: [{
       "locale": "en",
       "device": "web",
       "key": "server_url_dialog_default_button",
       "value": "en_test"
    }]
}
```

Since you're doing a `this.store.find()` and passing multiple parameters, Ember Data is expecting an array of results versus just a single result.  Hence, it is interpreting `device` as an entire model, versus an attribute of `uilabels`.